# converting bytes to string gives b' prefix

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm trying to convert an old python2 code to python3, and I'm facing a problem with `strings` vs `bytes`

In the old code, this line was executed:

```
'0x' + binascii.hexlify(bytes_reg1)
```

In python2 `binascii.hexlify(bytes_reg1)` was returning a `string` but in python3 it returns `bytes`, so it cannot be concatenated to `"0x"`

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

I tried converting it to string:

```
'0x' + str(binascii.hexlify(bytes_reg1))
```

But what I get as a result is:

```
"0xb'23'"
```

And it should be:

```
"0x23"
```

How can I convert the bytes to just `23` instead of b'23' so when concatenating '0x' I get the correct string?

Comment: Hi -- what is `bytes_reg1` here?

Comment: It's the restult of doing `bytes_reg1 = struct.pack(">H", reg1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try doing this and let me know whether it worked for you or not :

```
'0x' + str(binascii.hexlify(bytes_reg1)).decode("utf-8")
# or
'0x' + str(binascii.hexlify(bytes_reg1), encoding="utf-8")
```

note- Also if you can provide the sample of bytes_reg1, it will be easier to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Decode is the way forward, as @Satya says.

You can access the hex string in another way:

```py
>>> import binascii
>>> import struct
>>> 
>>> some_bytes = struct.pack(">H", 12345)
>>> 
>>> h = binascii.hexlify(some_bytes)
>>> print(h)
b'3039'
>>> 
>>> a = h.decode('ascii')
>>> print(a)
3039
>>> 
>>> as_hex = hex(int(a, 16))
>>> print(as_hex)
0x3039
>>>
```